# Redshift Connection not displaying any values in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, amazon-redshift

Hereby I have attached my code,

**server.js**

```
var Redshift = require('node-redshift');
   
const config = {
    user: *****,
    database: *****,
    password: *****,
    port: *****,
    host: '*****.redshift.amazonaws.com',
};

// The values passed in to the options object will be the difference between a connection pool and raw connection
var redshiftClient = new Redshift(config, {rawConnection:true});


exports.handler =  async (event) => {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

redshiftClient.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log("errror");
      throw err;
    }
    else{
      redshiftClient.parameterizedQuery('SELECT top 10 * FROM user', [event.user_id], {raw: true}, function(err, data){
        if(err){
          console.log("errror");
        }
        else{
          console.log(data);
          resolve(data);
          redshiftClient.close();
        }
      });
    }
  }); 
});

};
```

I have been trying to establish connection with redshift for data retrival, but end up with nothing displayed in the terminal for the given console.log command..